# Can switch SFP/SFP+ uplink ports connect to a SFP/SFP+ NIC and how?

Tags: networking

What I'm looking for is a solution to connect workstations with RJ-45 Ethernet NICs with a workstation with SFP/SFP+ NIC.

I found that many switches have both RJ-45 and SFP/SFP+ ports available, however, normally the SFP/SFP+ ports are uplinks used for switch-to-switch connection. From the definition of "uplink" (from http://www.linfo.org/uplink_port.html and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/954396/why-do-some-switches-have-uplink-ports), it seems that the only difference between a uplink port and normal "downlink" port is whether the TX/RX is crossed-over or not. So for RJ-45 based uplinks, if proper twist-cables are provided, I take that a uplink can be used to connect to a workstation (rather than another switch) just like other "downlink" ports.

Now here is my question, when the uplinks are SFP/SFP+ ports, do I need to use special "twisted" (probably not physically...) fiber cable to connect to a workstation with SFP/SFP+ NIC? Or, if direct attach cable (copper one) is used, do I need to cross-over the transmit and receive pair(s)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dedicate uplink ports are an anarchism from when MDI/MDI-X was not detected and account for by the switch software. In some cases you had a physical switch you needed to flip on the switch to turn it on or off.

That said, I don't think i've seen a switch that didn't have auto MDI/MDI-X capabilities (or it was controllable in software ) in about 8 years. You should be able to connect you workstation to an "Uplink" port and it'll work just fine. You *may* have to make software configuration adjustments in the switch config, you documentation should tell you if you need to and how to do it.

Comment: +1... pretty much anything with a GigE or 10GE PHY is going to Auto MDIX if the PHY vendor had a clue

Comment: Thanks, Zypher and Mike. This pretty much cleared my doubt.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense, but then why do all of these switch manufacturers all say uplink for these ports.  It makes no sense.